# gcov stopped to generate gcda file after added -rdynamic flag (__gcov_flush()  called through gdb)

Tags: c++, gdb, gcov

I've got some server in c++ (commands acquired from build-system):

```
g++ -o obj/server.o -c -m64 -isystem/opt/boost/include -Wall -Werror -march=core2 -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -DGCOV_ENABLED= -Iinclude -I/opt/hydraOST/lzopro/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Idaemon/include src/server.cpp

g++ -o bin/server.exe -rdynamic -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -m64 -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath=/opt/hydraOST/lzopro/lib  obj/server.o (+ other libs)
```

As it's daemon and I'm stopping it with signal but to enforce dumping gcov data before `kill $PID` I'm using *gdb*:

```
gdb -p $PID -batch -x gcov/dumpGcovData
```

where contents of *gcov/dumpGcovData*:

```
call __gcov_flush()
thread apply all call __gcov_flush()
```

I know that linking should be with `-lgcov` but as it was working in that way so I didn't change it in build system. The problem occured just after added `-rdynamic` flag (**without that flag it worked properly**).

Answer (score 1):

> I know that linking should be with -lgcov

That is incorrect: gcc will add `-lgcov` automatically given your flags; no explicit `-lgcov` needed.

> The problem occured just after added -rdynamic flag (without that flag it worked properly).

I can't imagine what `-rdynamic` may have to do with the problem. A trivial test case shows that it works *either* way, so either your claim of "it stopped working with addition of `-rdynamic`" is wrong, or there is some more complicated interaction going on (which I am not reproducing in my trivial test).

You may want to begin by

1. Verifying that in fact re-linking `server.exe` without `-rdynamic` as the *only* change makes it work again.
2. Showing the output from `g++ -o bin/server.exe ... -Wl,-y,__gcov_flush` and `readelf -s bin/server.exe | grep __gcov_flush`. Here is what it should look like:

   ```
   g++ -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs cov.c -g -rdynamic -Wl,-y,__gcov_flush
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): definition of __gcov_flush

   readelf -s a.out | grep gcov_fl
   66: 00000000004023c0   131 FUNC    LOCAL  HIDDEN   14 __gcov_flush
   ```

Comment: Ad.1 Yes, after removed `-rdynamic` flag coverage has been generated. I will do experiment with `readelf`, but when I had it compiled then `nm` showed that '__gcov_flush' was defined in `server.exe` (so invoking with __gcov_flush should work...)

Comment: "I can't imagine what -rdynamic may have to do with the problem" - yes, thats my main problem - note that there is also other binary that just ends normally and gcda file is generated properly. I suppose that `-rdynamic` just caused that somehow invoking `__gcov_flush` by `gdb` does not work... but have no idea why(?)

Comment: @ddzialak "have any idea why?" -- The output from commands in #2 may provide clues. Please run them and update your question with the output. *Then* someone may have an idea why. Alternatively, try to create a minimal test case that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After added `-Wl,-y,__gcov_flush` it printed out line (and flag `-rdynamic` does not matter):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): definition of __gcov_flush
```

Unfortunately, looks like `-rdynamic` flag does not afftect the output:

*with -rdynamic*:

```
readelf -s server.exe | grep gcov_flush
  1203: 0000000000808370   107 FUNC    LOCAL  HIDDEN   12 __gcov_flush
```

and *without -rdynamic*:

```
readelf -s server.exe | grep gcov_flush
  1203: 0000000000808380   107 FUNC    LOCAL  HIDDEN   12 __gcov_flush
```

Anyway, I've got very simple solution (or rather workaround): add -rdynamic ONLY if its build not for gcov:

```
if CONFIG == gcov:
    addFlags(["-ftest-coverage", "-fprofile-arcs"])
else:
    addFlags(["-rdynamic"])
```

So, main problem seems to be **not solved**, anyway got some workaround (works for me, because I rather don't use gcov config for debugging - just for generating coverage report). Anyway, thanks for help!